# Long names get truncated in DVDs

Tags: filenames, dvd-burning

I've burned a lot of files with big names on a DVD and most of them got truncated. I suppose it's because of the file system used on DVDs. But those names now end in weird capital-letter with numbers codes. What does that mean ? Is there a way to retrieve those names ?

P.S. All files are in root, no sub directories.

Comment: Can you please give us examples of some of the file names?

Comment: It seems my DVD burning app (Ashampoo) limits names to 123 characters. For instance the name 

_Expert Python Programming 2nd Edition - Become an ace Python programmer by learning best coding practices and Advanced-level Concepts With Python 3.5_ (148 characters)

Becomes

_Expert Python Programming 2nd Edition - Become an ace Python programmer by learning best coding practices and adva-QGUMEUNK_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are filenames shorter? The '[Joliet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joliet_(file_system))' filesystem for optical discs has an official 64 character (including spaces) length limit; the '[ISO9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660)' standard is even more restrictive, requiring a maximum of 8.3. Quoting from Wikipedia (op cit.):

> The specification only allows filenames to be up to 64 Unicode
>   characters in length. However, the documentation for [mkisofs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkisofs) states
>   filenames up to 103 characters in length do not appear to cause
>   problems.[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Ridge) Microsoft has documented it "can use up to 110
>   characters."

There's also a "[Rock Ridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Ridge)" standard with a cap of 255 characters (including spaces).

Your DVD burning app may be truncating file names and substituting other characters at the end of the character string.